# What is the meaning of underlined clause in following context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

[image]

Is this mean, when one ruler give grant to someone then new ruler also makes new grants following his ancestors traditions

And also here, ruler means Mughal emperor, local ruler, zamindar

Am I correct?

And what is the meaning of **grants were to be renewed by every ruler** here?

Comment: This site deplores posting of images; you should type the text or paste it, e.g. from [here](http://www.gideonhistory.com/EconomicandsocialStatusUnderMughals_eng.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although these grants were to be renewed by every ruler

Each new emperor/zamindar/noble was *supposed* to re-affirm the grants when they assumed power. Without this renewal the land would probably return to being owned by the new ruler.

> they often became hereditary in practice.

The land grants, instead of reverting to the ruler to be re-granted, stayed with the grantee despite the change in rulers. The grants would even pass down to the children of the original grantee and stay in the family from then on.

Comment: Here, ruler includes local ruler, zamindar in addition to Mughal emperor?

Comment: Yes, the word "ruler" in the underlined sentence refers back to **local rulers and zamindars, and even nobles, in addition to the Mughal emperor** in the previous sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The text is slightly ambiguous.

**Hereditary** (of a title, office, or right) conferred by or based on inheritance.

So the text could be saying that the granting of the right passed from one generation to another, presumably via the ruler and his/her offspring.

Or it might mean, and I think this is more likely, that the small tracts of land referred to passed down the generations without their ownership being officially renewed by the ruler. Sons and daughters merely took over the tracts of land from their parents.